# Are Cognito Forms accessible to screen readers?

Tags: cognito-forms, accessibility

Many of our consumers are blind and use screen readers like JAWS. Are Cognito forms screen reader accessible?

Answer (score 1):

I am a designer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Our public forms support the WCAG 2.0 AA accessibility guidelines put forth by the W3C. The goal of these guidelines is to make content accessible to everyone including those with disabilities. In order to support these guidelines, our forms use semantic markup including structural headings, fieldsets where appropriate, and the proper labeling of fields.

However, in our commitment to adhere to these guidelines we have identified some issues that we are currently working to resolve. These issues revolve around the keyboard accessibility of our toggle control for the Yes/No field, the dropdown for a Choice field only when you allow a fill-in option, and the File Upload field button.

If you encounter any accessibility issues, please [report them](https://www.cognitoforms.com/bugreport/) and we’ll do our best to resolve the issues as soon as we can.